# MongoDB Aggregate Match - check if value contains any of the given strings

Tags: javascript, mongodb, match, aggregate

I have the following types of documents in my mongodb. How can i use a match function to check if the key2 value contains 'Mermaid / Fairy' or 'Superhero'?

```
  {
    _id: 123,
    key2: [ 'Mermaid / Fairy', 'Superhero' ]
  } 
  {
    _id: 456,
    key2: [ 'Slug']
  }
```

This is how i am doing matches for individual words, however i would like to pass in a couple, and if it matches any of them, then it gets returned

```
    {
      $match: { key2: /.*Superhero.*/ },
    },
```

Comment: `"_id"` values need to be unique in the collection.  Perhaps you meant to include unique values?

Comment: @rickhg12hs yes, just amended, it was sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways ...

> to check if the key2 value contains 'Mermaid / Fairy' or 'Superhero'

... by checking if the `"$size"` of the `"$setIntersection"` of `"$key2"` and `["Mermaid / Fairy", "Superhero"]`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": {
              "$setIntersection": [
                "$key2",
                ["Mermaid / Fairy", "Superhero"]
              ]
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fl7iZmQieGg).

Another way is to use `"$reduce"` by checking each `"$key2"` value to see if it is `"$in"` `["Mermaid / Fairy", "Superhero"]`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$key2",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$or": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$in": [
                  "$$this",
                  ["Mermaid / Fairy", "Superhero"]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GChy0ZjemRk).

Comment: Will this work the same way? fieldValues = ["Mermaid / Fairy", "Superhero"] 
  fieldValues = fieldValues.join("|");      {
          $match: {
            key2: { $regex: fieldValues },
          },
        },

Comment: @TestUser In fact, it does!  Checkout this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/f1EGarzeqUc).  I hope you add it as another answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this aggregate

```
itemsSchema.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "key2": {
         $in: [
           "Mermaid / Fairy",
           "Superhero"
         ]
       }
   }
 }])
```

Comment: " ... however i would like to pass in a couple ..."  How does this answer accomplish this?

Comment: @rickhg12hs i din't understand what you want.

Comment: The question asks for "a match function to check if the key2 value contains 'Mermaid / Fairy' **_or_** 'Superhero'". [emphasis added]

Comment: @rickhg12hs i add another string in array.